# Angular mfe not loading lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation, mfe

I have angular shell app and angular mfe app.
My mfe has lazy loaded module inside it.
It works when i run the app without the shell but when i run it inside the shell the lazy loaded module is not found.
When load the module eagerly so no problem.
Is there solution for this?